# Reload component via <Link> in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to implement a facebook-like homepage (i.e. a list of posts with comments).

`PostList` is the component in charge of loading the post list (using fetch in its `componentDidMount()` ), itself being a child of the component `HomePage`.

I have another component for the navigation bar called `NavBar` with a `<Link>` component (from `react-router-dom`) to the route of my `HomePage` component ('/').

When I'm on any page other than '/', using the link works fine: the Router mounts `HomePage`, and then `PostList` triggering the `componentDidMount()` and displaying the freshly retrieved posts.

But when I'm already on '/' the Link does nothing because well I'm already on '/', but I'd like it to still reload my component `HomePage` so it can update its post list.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A React component re-renders only when it is given different `props` (or when it's `state` changes).
I had an issue similar to yours, and I solved it by passing a `timestamp` prop to the component everytime. That solved the issue for me. So inside you `<Router>` component, where you define the route for `Home` component, use the following code:

```
<Route path='/' component={ (props) => (
  <Home timestamp={new Date().toString()} {...props} />
)}/>
```

This way, the `timestamp` prop changes on subsequent clicks, and the component re-renders everytime you click the `<Link>`.

Comment: Gud One. Been searching abt it for a while :)

Comment: To make the reloading more responsive (less delay) use <Home timestamp={new Date().getTime().toString()} {...props} />

Answer (score 2):

I was solving a similar problem today. I had route:

```
<Route exact path="/:id" render={({ match }) => (<MyComponent match={match} />)} />
```

and link which did not invoke reload if `newId` was same as rendered `id`:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/${newId} }} >Go</Link>
```

The simplest solution I found was **adding new reload redirect** (right under route):

```
<Redirect from="/:id/reload" to="/:id" />
```

and changing link for `newId === id` to

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/${id}/reload` }} >Reload</Link>
```

I also found a solution with **adding new route with added timestamp** (like `1567430708808`):

```
<Route exact path="/:id/:ts" render={({ match }) => (<MyComponent match={match} />)} />
```

and reading it from `match` object for hooks, but timestamp occurred in URL and it was not as nice as the redirect. I need to mention I use react-router 5.0.1.