# react route direct to the same route not updating

Tags: reactjs

So this is my situation:

I have `App.jsx` that renders this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={MovieList} />
        <Route path="/search/:search" component={MovieList} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Now no matter if I'm on either one of these Routes, inside `MovieList` component there is a loop through list of `Movie`, and in each `Movie` there's a `<Link />` to the same Route, for example:

`<Link to="/search/goodmovie" />`

The thing is, if I click on that link, nothing happens, and it happens because its on the same route, if for example I changed it to something else, `<Link to="/blabla" />` it worked and redirected.

So how can I make it render again even if I want to link to the Route I'm currently in?

**Edit:** an example for a `Movie` component:

```
<div>
    <p class="text">{props.text}</p>
    <Link to="/search/test">Test link</Link>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post more code snippets, specifically of your movie list component ?

Comment: @mmaniatis added an example

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

From what you've showed I am thinking your seeing "nothing" happen as your routing to the same component:

You need to change that component, or else what should be changing? I am sure your seeing that /search/test being appended to the URL at least correct?

Can you add

```
<Route path="/search/:search" component={Home} />
```

For example?

If I am missing the point here I apologize, please provide more info so I can continue to help if this didn't resolve your issue.

Edit: Looks like this post may contain the solution already:

[Reload component via <Link> in React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792328/reload-component-via-link-in-react-router)

Comment: Yeah I can see the URL being changed correctly, but there is no update.
and the logic behind redirect to the same Route: every Movie has categories, so you can do something like `<Link to="search/category:Horror" />`, but since It's in the same Route, it doesn't make the change.

Comment: Well what are you expecting to update (As in what code should be firing, that isnt) ? Can you provide the code for that entire component, that will be useful I think.

Comment: I want it to re-render, like if it wasn't reloaded in the first place. the entire component has hundreds of irrelevant lines for code, but even that simple example didn't work.

Comment: Ah, I see. Okay please refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792328/reload-component-via-link-in-react-router Your issue is that you need to pass a new state/props to this component to reload. You can use that state/props to display a category of your movie.. etc.